# Can't change status bar style after applying pkrevealcontroller

Tags: statusbar

After apply view controller on pkrevealcontroller, the setting of status bar style just doesn't work.

Setup status bar style to black translucent in project setting => Not working.

Setup status bar style to black translucent in viewWillAppear method => Not working

Without pkrevealcontroller, anything is fine.

Is there anyway to resolve this?

```
My pkrevealController setup:
    MenuViewController *menuVC = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    PKRevealController *revealController = [PKRevealController revealControllerWithFrontViewController:self.tabBarController leftViewController:menuVC options:nil];
```

Set status bar style in viewWillAppear method:

```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:YES];
```

Thanks very much!